# React Native expo app: on Android emulator screen size different too physical device

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, expo

I am devlopeing a React Native app with expo on MacOS Big Sur and using a Android Emulator the same as my phone a Samsung Galaxy Note 9.

What Im finding is the sreen on the emulator has more space than my phone. I have checked the screen resolutions are the same in settings?

Any ideas why plz?

Malcolm

Comment: Due to the multitude of Android devices on market with various scale factors, pixel densities, React Native core units don't scale well for all devices, Read this article https://medium.com/react-native-training/build-responsive-react-native-views-for-any-device-and-support-orientation-change-1c8beba5bc23 and https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-screen